# How Best seller tables gets populated Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, cron, magento-cron, best-seller

There are 3 tables related to bestseller in Magento 2

```
 sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
 sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
 sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
```

How and when these tables get populated.
Is there any sort of `cron` that populates these tables as soon as a user completes an order?

data's are wrong on these 3 tables, 90% of products don't exist in catalog_product_entity 
That product_id from these 3 tables `sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
 sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
 sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly` doesn't exist anywhere

Answer (score 1):

When you "refresh statistics" for "Bestsellers Report" those tables get populated.

Refer magneto doc about reports : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/reports/product-reports.html

[image: refresh statistics link]

Comment: How about crontab.xml which has this code 
<job name="aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data"             instance="Magento\Sales\Model\CronJob\AggregateSalesReportBestsellersData" method="execute">
<schedule>0 0 * * *</schedule>
</job> , this states that the cron job will run every 00:00 hours, what does this cron job do ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I was wrong about cron job.